# iterate through 1 column, adding to new column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

Ive got a dataframe X, with 3 columns- accel, decel and stop.
There are 111110 rows.

I would like to iterate through the values in the accel column, so that if the value obeys a certain condition, a new value is created and saved in 'r' for each variable in the accel column of X.
I have the following code-

```
r=[]
pos=0
while pos<=111110:
for i in X['accel']:
    if i<10:
        r.append(1)
    elif 10<=i>=20:
        r.append(2)
    elif 20<=i>=30:
        r.append(3)
    elif 30<=i>=40:
        r.append(4)
    elif i>40:
        r.append(5)
        pos+=1

frames = [r,X]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

however when this runs, i only get

```
for i in X['accel']:
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

how can i make the code run through the full column of the dataframe and then print values of r as an additional column to the X dataframe?
Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure `10<=i>=20` doesn't give you the result you're looking for. It's only True when `i >= 20`.

Comment: Create some mock data of about 10 rows, the create the expected output to help use help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `pd.cut` will work

```
pd.cut(df.accel,bins=[-np.inf,10,20,30,40,np.inf],labels =[1,2,3,4,5])
Out[339]: 
0    1
1    1
2    4
3    5
4    5
Name: accel, dtype: category
Categories (5, int64): [1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5]
```

Comment: thats worked for me thank you so much for your help!